# htm form to disappear after submission

Tags: html, google-sites, forms, http-post

I am a bit new to coding. I have made a HTML form which is posting to one website after submission and is also landing on the other page for acknowledgement. but my form page is not disappearing. i am using google sites for this form so cant use any scripting language. Have to rely on html only

```
<form action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToCase?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
```

```
    <!-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
    <!-- NOTE: These fields are optional debugging elements. Please uncomment -->
    <!-- these lines if you wish to test in debug mode. -->
    <!-- <input type="hidden" name="debug" value=1>                              -->
    <!-- <input type="hidden" name="debugEmail" value="smoiz88@gmail.com">       -->
    <!-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
    <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
    <input id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="40" type="text" required />
    <br>
    <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
    <input id="last_name" maxlength="40" name="last_name" size="40" type="text" required />
    <br>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="40" type="text" required />
    <br>
    <label for="phone">Phone</label>
    <input id="phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="40" type="number" />
    <br>
    <label class="label">Site</label>
    <select class="select" id="Site" name="site" title="Site">
        <option value="None">None</option>
        <option value="Armadale">Armadale</option>
        <option value="Elsternwick">Elsternwick</option>
        <option value="Hawthorn">Hawthorn</option>
        <option value="Manila">Manila</option>
        <option value="UK">UK</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label class="label">Salesforce Profile</label>
    <select class="select" id="Profile">
        <option value="None">None</option>
        <option value="Acquire Career Champion">Acquire Career Champion</option>
        <option value="Acquire Career Advisor">Acquire Career Advisor</option>
        <option value="Acquire Career Hunter">Acquire Career Hunter</option>
        <option value="Acquire Data Analyst">Acquire Data Analyst</option>
        <option value="Acquire Retention Specialist">Acquire Retention Specialist</option>
        <option value="Acquire Training Admin">Acquire Training Admin</option>
        <option value="Acquire Qualifier">Acquire Qualifier</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="fault">Fault Title</label>
    <input id="fault" maxlength="20" name="fault" size="30" type="text" required />
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Fault Type</label>
    <select class="select" id="Type">
        <option value="None">None</option>
        <option value="Password Reset">Password Reset</option>
        <option value="Report Required">Report Required</option>
        <option value="Login Details">Login Details</option>
        <option value="End Of Employment">End Of Employment</option>
        <option value="File Merge">File Merge</option>
        <option value="Insufficient Privilege">Insufficient Privilege</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="description">Description</label>
    <textarea name="description"></textarea>
    <br>
    <div id="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </div>

</form>
```

any suggestions how can i make it disapper once it is submitted.

Comment: uncomment the debug section and set the email to your address and post the response.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the server brings you back because it doesn't know where to redirect after form submission. 
Try create another page with confirmation text and configure server to redirect there after submission. 
There must be a parameter or something on the server side to control submission behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. but the form page is not moving from its place when the acknowledgment page opens up in the new window..how can i make a form page to open up a new window containing the acknowledgement.

Comment: _the form page is not moving from its place when the acknowledgment page opens up in the new window_
and at the same time
_how can i make a form page to open up a new window containing the acknowledgement_
cant figure out whether acknowledgement page shows up in new window?